# Последовательное использование всех строк таблицы.

Tags: php, циклы, mysql

В общем, нужно сделать следующее: извлечь все строки из БД и пробежаться с этими данными через file_get_contents. В таблице вбиты несколько тысяч строк, столбцы: directiry, file.
Нужно как то сделать, что бы скрипт циклом пробегался по всем записям directory/file,
короче, для каждой строки, свой запрос.

Пытаюсь вывести данные, но по ходу криво

```
<?php
error_reporting();
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('links');

$qu = mysql_query("select * from test");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($qu);
$qu = mysql_fetch_assoc($qu);
print_r($qu);
?>
```

Выводит только первую строку. Как мне внести ВСЕ из таблицы, скажем, в массик и сделать запрос для этих самых строк?

Comment: Документацию ([например][1]), читать не пробовали? Говорят, помогает. Там всё большими красивыми буковками есть, даже с примерами...


  [1]: http://www.php.su/mysql_fetch_array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это извращение..)

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($qu); $qu = mysql_fetch_assoc($qu);
```

Извините, конечно, но выберите что-то одно. Так никто не делает.
А **по вопросу**:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qu)){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=links', 'root', '');

$dbh = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM test;");
$dbh->execute();

$data = $dbh->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre>';
```